# Cpanel API keeps responding with access denied

Tags: php, api, cpanel

I'm trying to get CPanel API with tokens working and using the following code (from the Cpanel API docs).

```
$query = "https://example.com:2083/json-api/listaccts?api.version=1";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$header[0] = "Authorization: cpanel $user:$token";
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

$http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($http_status != 200) {
    echo "[!] Error: " . $http_status . " returned\n";
} else {
    $json = json_decode($result);
    echo "[+] Current cPanel users on the system:\n";
    foreach ($json->{'data'}->{'acct'} as $userdetails) {
        echo "\t" . $userdetails->{'user'} . "\n";
    }
}

curl_close($curl);
```

Of course example.com is the replaced with the url of my server and $user and $token are filled with the right info.

But the result keeps telling me access denied
I also tried port 2087 but still the same response

Update: I got it working with an API token on the WHM user (root) but I want to use it on a cPanel user API token.

Comment: Can you please link to the documentation section that you are referring to?

Comment: https://api.docs.cpanel.net/guides/guide-to-api-authentication/guide-to-api-authentication-api-tokens-in-whm#php